# Find the length of a key, value chain in a multimap

Tags: c++, recursion, multimap

I have a networking program that lets the user add 2 people to a multimap. The key is recruiter and the value is the person they add, the value can add another person so on and so forth. Here is an example

```
> add john mary
> add john tom
> add mary brad
> add tom Maria
> add mary Eli
> add brad Sofia
```

If I were to print john's chain, then I'd get the following.

```
> p john
john
..mary
....brad
......sofia
....eli
..tom
....maria
```

I need to find a way to count the length of the chain. In this case, length of john's chain is 6 and Mary has a length of 3.

This is how I print the chain

```
void print_subnet(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>networkMap, std::string id, size_t count=2)
{
    for(auto itr = networkMap.begin(); itr != networkMap.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(itr ->first == id)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(count, '.') << itr -> second << std::endl;
            print_subnet(networkMap, itr->second, count+2);
        }

    }
}
```

I followed a similar logic to get the chain length.

- for a given key, get the count.
- set the value of the key as the new key
- repeat until the end of map.

Here is my code.

```
 int count_size(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>networkMap, std::string id, int count)
    {
        for(auto itr = networkMap.begin(); itr != networkMap.end(); ++itr)
        {
            if(itr->first == id)
              {
                count += networkMap.count(id);
                count_size(networkMap, itr->second, count);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I get the answer 4, when it's supposed to be 6. I printed out the count value and this is what I got.

```
2 (2 from john)
4 (2 from mary)
5 (1 from brad)
6 (1 from tom)
4 ??
5 ??
4 ??
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple, but I've been at this for a while, I can't think straight.

Comment: What do you do with the result that the recursive `count_size` call returns?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just call this function in a ´std::cout' I don't do anything to the result.

Comment: Maybe you should use the result that the ***recursive*** calls to `count_size` returns? As in `count += count_size(...)`?

Comment: And you should also get some sleep. Thing always seems clearer after a good nights sleep. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for the dumb question! do you mean add a 'return count_size(networkMap, itr->second, count);' after I increment 'count'?

Comment: No, just add to the variable `count` (like I shown). And you should not pass `count` as an argument, just define it as a local variable inside the function and initialize it to zero.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that almost worked, but it exits a loop early. so only gave me 5!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns 6:

```
void count_size_recursive(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>networkMap, std::string id, int& count)
{
  for(auto itr = networkMap.begin(); itr != networkMap.end(); ++itr)
  {
    if(itr->first == id)
    {
      ++count;
      count_size_recursive(networkMap, itr->second, count);
    }
  }
}

int count_size(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>networkMap, std::string id)
{
  int count = 0;
  count_size_recursive(networkMap, id, count);
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers, as that generally promotes [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad. Try to explain what changes you made, how the code differs from the one in the question, what it does, and *why* it does what it do. Also please read [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, the main idea is that you just need to increment count variable once for every match and move on the chain. There is no need to call the `count` method when you advanced to the next element because just one element is found and `count` method counts all elements. And you need somehow to return incremented counter to the caller so there are two possibilities: reference parameter or return value. I chose the first one because I think it's simpler and clearer.